Access XP doesn't start
I have this problem:
On a PC with Windows 10 Professional, MS Access 2021 (MSO LTSC Professional Plus 2021) and MS Access XP are installed. For the past few days, MS Access XP has been closing shortly after the application starts. The event log contains the following entries:
Faulting application name: MSACCESS.EXE, version: 10.0.2627.1, time stamp: 0x3aa5f86a
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x001989d4
Faulting process ID: 0x39f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01dae70d0a052223
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office10\MSACCESS.EXE
Faulting module path: unknown
Report ID: 2b1a4a96-791e-4b54-9567-010393f3781d
Full package name of the faulting package:
Application ID relative to the faulting package:
MS Access XP has already been reinstalled, unfortunately without success. Could someone please help me with this problem?
Thank you very much for any help!

Repairing the Access XP installation
Reinstalling MS Access XP
Running in compatibility mode
The application still crashes shortly after opening.


Sorry for the broken link to the Access 2010 runtime downloads on our Access version comparison page: https://fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/history/features.htm
We updated that page and pointed it to a single Runtime Download page for all the Access versions. That eliminates the need to manage download links across multiple pages (like normalizing a table):
https://fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/runtime/index.htm
There are links for Access 2010's 32-bit and 64-bit runtime downloads. Note that there are two sets: one for SP2 and one for the original version with a link to a page explaining the differences. Go with SP2.
Hope this helps.

Access XP/2002 is so much out of support.
"Upgrade" to the latest version that supports ADP files, 2010:
https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/history/features.htm
That page of FMS Inc. also holds a link to the 2007 runtime; the link to the 2010 runtime, however, is broken.

Yes, I know this is an extremely old application. But we still need it for some time until the migration to Access 2021 is complete. Until then, unfortunately, we have to use both versions.

You could try a fresh install of a non-updated build of Windows 10 and Access XP. But if that fails, resistance is probably futile. Update at least to Access 2007. Do note, that Access 2016 and later will not run adp applications.

As long as the OP is intent on running Office 2021 together with an older version of Office, I'm not sure this is good advice. I strongly recommend not to (and to use a VM if you need an old version, also for security reasons), but in the past I've had the best experience with 2007 and older. Of course, using Office XP is not really acceptable, it's over 13 years out of support so migration should've happened at least a decade ago

@ErikA: It must be Access 2007/2010 only. These can't coexist with newer versions if same bitness. Perhaps 2007 (which is 32-bit) and 2021 64-bit can, but I would not count on it.

@Gustav IIRC I had 2003 and 2010 32-bits running simultaneously on the same machine at some time (2003 was needed to upgrade MDB files from Access 3.0 to 2003, so that they could then be upgraded further by 2010). But this is all long ago. Having multiple versions of Access running simultaneously became more trouble starting with Office 2010 I think.

@ErikA: Yes, earlier versions could live side-by-side, but the newer version are much more prudish.

Unfortunately, we still need the extremely old version of Access this year. So far, the coexistence of Access XP and 2021 has worked. I can imagine that perhaps an update to Access 2021 was the trigger. Since a reinstallation of Access XP also brought no success, I fear that registry entries are missing or contain incorrect references. I think, as Erik.A suggested, that moving to a VM might be the quickest and easiest solution.
Thank you all very much for your support!

A VM with Windows 10 32-bit should work. I have it running with A2003, A2000, and Access 2.0(!) coexisting nicely. No Access XP, though.
